# Display a single tooltip with Chart.JS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've made a chart using Chart.JS and am hoping to limit the tooltip display to 1 single point.  I have a working demo where all tooltips are currently being displayed that can be viewed here: https://jsfiddle.net/p2yd6hut/

```
var data1 = {
  labels : ["SUN","MON","TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT"],
  datasets : [
{
  fillColor : "rgba(255,255,255,.1)",
  strokeColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.25)",
  pointColor : "#0af",
  pointStrokeColor : "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
  pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
  pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
  data : [150,200,235,390,290,250,250]
    }
 ]
}

var options1 = {
  scaleFontColor : "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
  scaleLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
  scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
  scaleShowGridLines : true,
  scaleShowLabels : false,
  scaleShowHorizontalLines : false,
  bezierCurve : false,
  scaleOverride : true,
  scaleSteps : 5,
  scaleStepWidth : 100,

  tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %>" + "Guests",
  showTooltips: true,
  tooltipFillColor: "#0af",  
  onAnimationComplete: function() {    
  this.showTooltip(this.datasets[0].points, true);          
    },
  tooltipEvents: []

}

new Chart(c1.getContext("2d")).Line(data1,options1);
```

Is it possible to only have a tooltip display for a selected datapoint? For instance, I'd like to only have Wednesday where the data is 390 in the array.

Screenshot of desired functionality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKYtx.png

Advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/p2yd6hut/2/
on the function onAnimationComplete i have created a new temp array with the value >= to 390

```
onAnimationComplete: function()
    {    var tempArr = [];
     this.datasets[0].points.forEach(function(point){
         if(point.value >= 390){
             tempArr.push(point);
         }
     });
        this.showTooltip(tempArr, true);          
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @fermin-perdomo, this accomplishes what I am looking for in this instance!  For the sake of sustainability, is it possible to instead target the label?  Only problem I can see with this solution is that if there are multiple values of 390, a tooltip for each one will be displayed.  My eventual usage of this concept will have the displayed tooltip changing based on day of the week.

Comment: You welcome. Yes you can use this to get the target label point.label, good luck!!!